# WSLv2 mount option missing from wsl util

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, mount

I'm using wslv2 on Windows 10 Pro running on the dev channel. I've made sure it's fully up to date, then completely uninstalled wsl and ubuntu, then reinstalled them.

Despite this, I don't have a working mount option :(

```
wings@machine:~$ wsl --mount
Unknown command: --mount
```

Comment: Are you running Windows Insider preview build 20211 ? What does the command `[Environment]::OSVersion` output?

Comment: Absolute latest build on the Dev channel.

Don't have the full paste but 10.0.21301.0

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to do this from the wsl terminal. But this must be done through powershell.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the `--mount` option being not yet released.

The documentation on Microsoft doesn't highlight it very much but you have to use early windows 11 preview to be able to use the mount option.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk#prerequisites

From what I understand [there](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/6061#discussioncomment-493105), the actual release is scheduled for *this* month (Sept. 21) in Win 10.

Comment: A very very miserable experience of waiting for a much demanded feature for several years...